# Ola Hallengren - Backupdatabase Task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ola-hallengren

When running **Ola's full SQL Server Maintenance Solution** or the individual databasebackup script I get the following error:

> MSG 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 1545
>   Invalid column name 'schemaName'.

This is part of the `@databasesInParallel` section which it appears to be trying to run even though this variable is set to `'N'` at the beginning of the script. I haven't altered anything and this script works perfectly on other servers.

Comment: Does this server have a case sensitive collation?

Comment: Hi Erik, no checked that CI_AS , should have put that in the main issue

Comment: Do you by any chance have a different dbo.Queue table in your database? If I create the Queue table without the schemaName column, it gives me the exact same error while @databasesinParallel = 'N' :  
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 1545 [Batch Start Line 5]
Invalid column name 'SchemaName'. (3 times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dbo.Queue` table exists, but does not have the `SchemaName` column.
This can be due to a custom dbo.Queue table that has nothing to do with Ola's solution. You could rename the table in the maintenance plan or drop the existing tables.

**Recreating the error**

Step 1: Recreate the maintenance solution Procedure

Step 2 Create the `dbo.Queue` table without the `SchemaName`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Queue]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Queue](
  [QueueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  --  [SchemaName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
  [ObjectName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
  [Parameters] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
  [QueueStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [SessionID] [smallint] NULL,
  [RequestID] [int] NULL,
  [RequestStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Queue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
  [QueueID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
END
GO
```

Step 3: Create the `dbo.QueueDatabase` table

Step 4: Try to take a backup

```
USE [MNGDB]
GO

EXEC  [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
        @Databases = N'MNGDB',
        @Directory = N'G:\Data',
        @BackupType = N'FULL'
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 1545
>   [Batch Start Line 5] Invalid column name 'SchemaName'. Msg 207, Level
>   16, State 1, Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 1555 [Batch Start Line
>   5] Invalid column name 'SchemaName'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>   Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 1561 [Batch Start Line 5] Invalid
>   column name 'SchemaName'.

---

**Why**

The query fails because the table exists but the `schemaname` column does not.
If table does not exist, it succeeds.

---

**Testing the part that causes the error & resolving it**

```
  DECLARE @DatabasesInParallel char(1)  = 'N', @SchemaName varchar(255) = 'test',  @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max)
  IF @DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'
  BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

      SELECT  QueueID
      FROM dbo.[Queue]
      WHERE SchemaName = @SchemaName


    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
      IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
      BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      END
      SET @ErrorMessage = 'Msg ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS nvarchar) + ', ' + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '
      RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
    END CATCH

  END
```

Error message

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1892
Invalid column name 'SchemaName'.
```

Dropping the two previously created tables

```
drop table dbo.[QueueDatabase]; 
drop table dbo.[Queue];
```

and rerunning the statement produces no error:

> Commands completed successfully.

Comment: Randi, spot on mate .. checked and the QueueDatabase table exists, thanks for putting this much effort in.

Comment: @Stockburn awesome, glad it helped!

Comment: Yes, this is what happened. This is the risk when I introduce new tables. I am considering moving the SQL Server Maintenance Solution to its own schema because of this.
https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/91